# Search for element value in an XML file

Tags: java, xml, xpath

In a given XML file, I'm trying to search for the presence of a string using `XPath` in Java. However,  even though the string is there, my output is always coming up as a No. Hoping someone here can point out  what I may be doing wrong?

**XML File:**

```
<article>
 <body>
  <section>
    <h1>intro1</h1>
    <region>introd1</region>
    <region>introd2</region>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1 class="pass">1 task objectives</h1>
    <region>object1</region>
    <region>object2</region>
  </section>
  <section>
     <h1 class="pass">1 task objectives</h1>
     <region>object1</region>
     <region>This is the Perfect Word I am looking for</region>
  </section>
 </body>
</article>
```

Within Java, I'm trying to check for the presence of the word `"perfect"` like this:

```
expr = xpath.compile("//article//body//section//region[contains(.,'perfect')]");
object result = expr.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList)result;

if (nodes.getLength() > 0) { 
    System.out.println("Found");
    // do other stuff here
} else {
    System.out.println("Not found");
}
```

When I run this, the output is always `"Not Found"`. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I tested this...

```
expr =xpath.compile("/article/body/section/region[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'perfect')]");
```

Against

```
<article>
    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>intro1</h1>
            <region>perfect</region>
            <region>Perfect</region>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1 class="pass">1 task objectives</h1>
            <region>pErFeCt</region>
            <region>Not Perfect</region>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h1 class="pass">1 task objectives</h1>
            <region>object1</region>
            <region>This is the Perfect Word I am looking for</region>
        </section>
    </body>
</article>
```

Using...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class TestXML05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            Document doc = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("Sample.xml"));

            XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
            XPath xPath = xFactory.newXPath();
            XPathExpression exp = xPath.compile("/article/body/section/region[contains(translate(text(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'perfect')]");

            NodeList nl = (NodeList)exp.evaluate(doc.getFirstChild(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
            for (int index = 0; index < nl.getLength(); index++) {

                Node node = nl.item(index);
                System.out.println(node.getTextContent());

            }


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestXML05.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Which outputted...

```
perfect
Perfect
pErFeCt
Not Perfect
This is the Perfect Word I am looking for
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The text() in Contains/Translate did the trick I guess?

Comment: That's my guess (I had a similar issue over the weekend and `text()` was the bases of the solution)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for the answer and @BRZ please accept the answer, so that later visitors can easily find the working solution.

Answer (score 2):

XML/XPath are case-sensitive, your XPath should be

```
//article//body//section//region[contains(., 'Perfect')]
```

To make case-insensitive, use this

```
//article//body//section//region[
    contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
    'perfect')
]
```

Comment: Tried that using the exact match as well. I still get a "Not Found" message.