# Document.toString() is "[#document: null]" even though XML was parsed

Tags: java, xml

Consider this example

```
@Test
    public void testXML() {
        final String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><results>\n" +
                "    <status>OK</status>\n" +
                "    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>\n" +
                "    <url/>\n" +
                "    <language>english</language>\n" +
                "    <docSentiment>\n" +
                "        <type>neutral</type>\n" +
                "    </docSentiment>\n" +
                "</results> ";

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder;
        try
        {
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( s ) ) );
            System.out.println(doc.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I run this example
`System.out.println(doc.toString());` turns out to be `[#document: null]`.

I also validated this XML online and no errors were found. What am I missing?

**What I need?**

I need to find out value of `<docSentiment>` in this `XML`

Thanks

Comment: updated my output, it is `[#document: null]`

Comment: The Document is null, but one it's root properties, which it uses to generate the output, is. Try processing the document in some way and you'll see its fine...

Comment: @MadProgrammer, sorry but I did not understand what you mean

Comment: To find an element in XML, use xPath [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139759/search-for-element-value-in-an-xml-file/17139865#17139865),

Comment: The document isn't "null", but something that it uses to generate the out put for toString is, doesn't mean the document isn't loaded, because it is, you need to start processing it

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* The answer is you making assumptions on limited information, or nothing really.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, I tried as per your advice and it worked! a lot of thanks for your guidance

Comment: the Document#toString() method is always giving this kind of useless representation. If you want to access elements you can use xpath or the DOM API. The later is rather ugly as you have to cast between Nodes and Elements, use getElementsByTag name, retrieve NodeLists by Index and handle all kinds of different types. That is better done in JDom with the `getChild(name)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `MadProgrammer`'s advice, I managed to get the value.

Note: Even though [#document: null] was shown, the document was not null, in reality.

```
@Test
public void testXML() {
    final String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><results>\n" +
            "    <status>OK</status>\n" +
            "    <usage>By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html</usage>\n" +
            "    <url/>\n" +
            "    <language>english</language>\n" +
            "    <docSentiment>\n" +
            "        <type>neutral</type>\n" +
            "    </docSentiment>\n" +
            "</results>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try
    {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( s ) ) );

        XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//docSentiment/type");
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("Sentiment:" + ((DTMNodeList) nl).getDTMIterator().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and I go the output as

```
Sentiment:neutral
```