# Search for a Element Value and the next sibling Element Value (only the value) in an XML - JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xpath

XML looks like this :

```
<abc:employee>
  <abc:name>SALARY</abc:name>
  <abc:value>Yes</abc:value>
  <abc:previousValue/>
  <abc:qualification>
      <abc:code>Basic</abc:code>
  </abc:qualification>
</abc:employee>
```

Need to search for 'SALARY' and get the value of the next tag i.e., 'Yes'

How do I do this? tried the XPath way, code looks like :

```
XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression xPathExpr = xpath.compile("//*[contains(., 'SALARY')]");

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("emp.xml");

        NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPathExpr.evaluate(doc.getFirstChild(), XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println(nl.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {

            System.out.println(nl.item(i).getTextContent());
        }
```

got some idea from [Search for element value in an XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139759/search-for-element-value-in-an-xml-file)
Also, how do I get only the Element Value? in this case just - 'Yes' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use following xpath:

```
string(//*[.='SALARY']/following-sibling::*)
```

this xpath on evaluation returns string `Yes` on your xml

Comment: string(//*[.='SALARY']/following-sibling::*[1]) this one did it! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this XPath expression instead, to get the nearest element following the element containing text `'SALARY'` :

```
//*[contains(., 'SALARY')]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

Comment: How do I get only the value of the Element Value?